# Как подключиться к устройствам компьютера с помощью C++ (ввод/вывод)?

Tags: c++, ос

Как подключиться к устройствам компьютера с помощью C++ (ввод/вывод информации без ОС)?
И я хочу начать создавать простую операционную систему на C++. Уже изучаю "[Архитектуру ЭВМ и основы ОС](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVZrHGNGvb0)",["Операционные системы"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDVGRWdtsWI&index=1&list=PLZbigOdn1qDLDsQ7joKDiNhBT8md-lzxx)
Посоветуйте что нибудь почитать или по смотреть...

Comment: я бы начинал делать с чистого Си. Плюсы позже понадобятся. Посмотреть можно к примеру на [KolibriOS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KolibriOS).

По факту - найдите любую старую книгу, которая описывает, как работать с прерываниями биоса (на новых компах теперь UEFI - как с ним - не знаю). Если разберетесь с прерываниями биоса - получите доступ к жесткому (правда с определенными ограничениями), видео, клавиатуре и другим мелким устройствам.

Comment: Ага, сейчас тут вам расскажут, что операционные системы только на си пишутся, а с++ вообще жутко плохой язык и писать на нем нельзя.

Comment: да можно и на плюсах, только придется немного пошаманить. Эксперты он висту на шарпе писали, только потом переписали назад.

Но если @0x0001 умеет на плюсах - то кто ему мешает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще делать конечно на Си, так как при разработке вы спуститесь на низкий уровень, где все плюсы этого языка становятся бесполезны. Но в общем-то никто не запрещает. Для операционных систем есть две фундаментальные книги:

1. Архитектура компьютера - Э. Таненбаум
2. Операционные системы: разработка и реализация - Э. Таненбаум

К последней прилагается в свободном доступе исходный код учебной [ОС Minix](http://www.minix3.org/), где можно посмотреть простенькую реализацию.

Если же говорить о том, как общаться с системой без ОС, в том числе без DOS, то описание архитектуры есть в [Intel® 64 IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) (к слову в самом [pdf 3000+ страниц](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf)).

Ну и конечно, если чисто для тестирования, желательно найти систему позволяющую  управлять процессором напрямую.